# Blender subdivision surface, mirror modifier issues

Tags: 3d, blender, modeling, mirror, modifier

I am new to Blender and I'm currently trying to model Goku from DragonBall GT. I started from a Cube and i modified it to a simple humanoid model using a mirror modifier. After I applied the mirror modifier on the object i tried to subdivide the surface of the mesh. The results where decent except the fact that in some areas mostly in the middle of the character things are messed up.

See Figure 1 below, shows an example of the issue mentioned above.

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: First enable merge and clipping in the mirror modifier, you may need to move the central vertices a little so the mirrored verts align at the centre. You also need to [remove the internal faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46355/935) that you have down the centre of your model.

Answer (score 1):

It looks there are some faces inside your mesh, where he is supposed to be mirrored. Remove them, you shouldn't have faces inside such mesh.

Then, a few things:
Don't apply your modifiers unless you need to. Modifiers are made to be non-destructive editable, removable. If you apply your modifiers, you lose all that, losing flexibility, performances, ...

In your mirror modifier, you might want do enable *Merge* and *Clipping*. Merge will allow the modifier to merge overlapping vertices into one while clipping will "block" your vertices from going through the mirroring plane.
Then, you might need to adjust your mesh. The mirror modifier uses the object's origin to determine where he works. If your mesh isn't correctly positioned from your object origin, you will need to adjust it.

About the black faces, it's because their [normals](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html) are inverted. Simply select them in edit mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate the normals. You might need to invert the result (via the invert checkbox in the left bar or in the <kbd>F6</kbd> menu).